# Spark : LI Class depndant on IF condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MVC3 and Spark.

I need to add a class to a LI if a certain ViewBag element is set to X.

```
<li id="menu-home" class="active?{ViewBag.Active=='home'}" >${Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Site")}</li>
```

Like the above. This doesnt work, however wondering if there is a way to approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps I took and it worked for me:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project using the default template and the Razor view engine
2. Install the `Spark.Web.Mvc3` NuGet package.
3. Change the `Index` action of `HomeController` to look like this:

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       ViewBag.Active = "home";
       return View();
   }
   ```
4. Rename `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` to `~/Views/Home/Index.spark` and make it look like this:

   ```
   <li id="menu-home" class="active?{ViewBag.Active == 'home'}">
       ${Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Site")}
   </li>
   ```
5. Run the project
6. The generated HTML is:

   ```
   <li id="menu-home" class="active">
       <a href="/Site">Home</a>
   </li>
   ```

Remark: Everytime I see someone using ViewBag instead of strongly typed views with view models I feel in the obligation to point this as a bad practice.